# Computer with Kali Linux, trying to wipe and install Windows, can't boot to Windows install media

Tags: boot, bootloader, kali-linux, windows-installation

I have installed Kali Linux because i want to learn some of the cyber security related things but now i wanted to go back to my Windows. As i had not much more knowledge about dual boot of system so i installed Kali Linux with single boot and now my boot loader is grub boot loader so how can i remove Kali Linux from my laptop and install windows 10.

I have a bootable Windows 10 CD, but starting the computer just brings up Grub and I cannot get the computer to boot to the Windows 10 install disk.

Comment: The way to install Windows in a blank drive or in drive with another OS already installed isn't much different. What exactly is problem? What step in the Windows installation were you unable to perform, what errors? Please [edit] the question with meaningful information so to make it answerable. As it is now, nobody can answer.

Comment: I can't even go to the boot menu. Kali linux is single booted in my pc i just want to remove this from my computer and install new os.

Comment: Have you downloaded the Windows 10 ISO, installed it on a USB drive and booted from that? "I had tried to install by many ways," is not very informative.

Comment: Yes i Have boot able CD of windows 10. But i can't boot from that.

Comment: If so your problem is not with the installation. You aren't at it yet. How to boot external media depends on your hardware. Typically there's a key to access BIOS/UEFI settings and some also have an alternative key for a one-time boot menu that allows selecting a different boot device. I wonder *how* have you installed Kali the first time because the procedure is the same?

Comment: when i try to boot it loads the same grub boot loader screen and dont launch windows installation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When booting, you should see a message from the BIOS about the key to use
for entering the BIOS (typically <kbd>F2</kbd>), and the key for a one-time
boot menu (typically <kbd>F12</kbd>).

Type the boot-menu key repeatedly when the computer boots, and when it appears
choose the USB device of the Windows installation.
If this doesn't work, use the BIOS key to change the boot-order to USB-first
(you will have to undo it later).

When you manage to get into the Windows installation setup,
reformat the disk to erase all traces of the Kali installation.

Comment: `F12` seems to be pretty common for one-time boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the same problem you are currently going through. To fix this issue, I made an Ubuntu install USB. Using this boot drive, I entered the Ubuntu operating system without installing. Once in, I opened G parted and formatted the partitions to ntfs. Once you confirm all the actions, remove the live USB, insert your windows disc, and proceed happily.